# Changing OpenVPN-AS root CA

Tags: openvpn, certificate-authority

I'm trying to set up an OpenVPN-AS instance (on an Azure virtual machine) that users can connect to and connect to some IoT devices behind routers in the field where the routers support OpenVPN.

My intention is to create users on the OpenVPN-AS and have them connect by downloading their client.ovpn from the server, but provision the routers with a client certificate from my own self signed CA.

I've followed the howto guide on all of this but the one thing I'm terminally stuck on is that the server won't use my CA. I've uploaded it to the web server page, verified it's in the openvpn directory and I can see it embedded as a comment in the client.ovpn when it's created but the CA that the server produces is the OpenVPN CA certificate. The only place I can see it used is as the certificate for the admin page.

It sounds like it's only being used to secure the web interface and not the actual server itself. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can get OpenVPN-AS to use my CA and server certificate/key to validate connections instead of its own?

Comment: What do you mean by the server won't use your CA? You mean for the client? It's loading for the 943 and 443 pages though?

Comment: Loading 943 gives me the security warning to accept my CA, but when I then download the client.ovpn file and open it up, the CA is that of Open VPN.
I want to upload my own CA for use with the vpn side of things rather than with the web browser side so I can issue client certificates myself rather than creating new users on the server and downloading the certs it creates.